# Docker inside ubuntu 18.04 docker image not running

Tags: docker, containers

I have installed a ubuntu 18.04 container inside which I tried to start the docker service. I got the error,

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Is it possible to run docker inside a docker image? How do I give the privilege to run the nested image?

Comment: You need to post this in unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I have tried all these steps. It is not working. I got the same error

Comment: This comes up quite often when trying to build bitbucket or Jenkins CI pipelines, bitbucket for example allows to specifiy docker as a service. A good answer to your questions is available here: https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/

Comment: I have installed docker inside the ubuntu 18 container. When I try to view the images using docker images command, i get this error.

Comment: docker version ?

Comment: First of all see if docker is running by command `systemctl status docker`, if it's not running then run it by `systemctl start docker` and `systemctl enable docker` (both of them).

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try as an elevated user: `sudo systemctl start docker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run docker inside docker then you have to use dind images

> ```
> docker run --privileged --name some-docker -v /my/own/var-lib-docker:/var/lib/docker -d docker:dind
> ```

Another way, If you want to run docker inside ubuntu container then you have to mount
docker.sock  of your host machine into your ubuntu container using docker volume

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:18.04
```

Comment: Instead of ubuntu:18.04, I replaced my image id. 
Thank you very much.. it worked for me  :)

Answer (score 0):

This comes up quite often when trying to build bitbucket or Jenkins CI pipelines, bitbucket for example allows to specifiy docker as a service. A good answer to your questions is available here: https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/

As given in first option in the article,it is possible to map host docker service inside of docker instance as below:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti docker-image`

Comment: I have tried the above command and go this error     docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.